# What do you call a type of person you don't want to become?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives, synonyms, vocabulary

Say this person had every single personality trait that you despised. Somebody that you don't want to be like or be associated with. What would this type of person be called?

Comment: An [**undesirable**?](http://www.memidex.com/undesirable+unwelcome-person)

Comment: I think there are a number of different possible terms, depending on register (formal vs. informal, etc.). Right now there I can't tell from your question whether you'd prefer something like *negative role model*, something like *repugnant asshole*, something like *snake* . . .

Comment: "Object lesson"

Comment: For many teenagers, the word would be "Mother" or "Father" (usually the parent of the same gender as the offspring).

Comment: If you can't be anything else you can be a *bad example*.

Comment: Your *antithesis*.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these below:

**Repulsive**; arousing intense distaste or disgust.

**Loathsome**; causing hatred or disgust; repulsive.

**Detestable**; deserving intense dislike.

**Abhorrent**; inspiring disgust and loathing; repugnant.

**Odious**; extremely unpleasant; repulsive.

**Repugnant**; extremely distasteful; unacceptable.

Repulsive, loathsome, detestable are pretty common words.

Comment: I think OP is looking for something like the opposite of role-model.

Comment: And these traits are definitely not role-model. Also; dirt-bag, jerk, louse, scum, scumbag, sleaze comes to my mind that are clearly not a role model.

Comment: I guess my point was that while these traits apply perfectly to a person who would be an anti-role-model, they do not ***mean*** an anti-role-model.

Comment: The phrase: "He's a model student" suggests a person who encompasses all the positive traits a teacher expects from a pupil. I agree with Jim that the OP is looking for a single-word that tells you this is a person is the **complete opposite** of a model student/worker/boss etc..

Comment: I understand that but that word I can't find.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***antimodel***?

> : someone or something that serves as the opposite of a model, representing what one does not want to be or achieve. [Your Dictionary](//www.yourdictionary.com/antimodel#BsUjmlIB1o87wWfs.99)

Answer (score 0):

I'd call the person "the antithesis to my ideals".

From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:

> antithesis
>         n 1: exact opposite; "his theory is the antithesis of mine"
>         2: the juxtaposition of contrasting words or ideas to give a
>            feeling of balance